# MySQL How to get all ids of affected rows after INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE with multiple values inserted

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I have 2 codependent table that store id of each other respectively.

eg:

- person_info (id, extra_id, first, last, email)
- extra_info (id, person_info_id, extra1, extra2)

I have a large collection of rows that I need to insert in db from excel file and it contains both person_info and extra_info, also I need to update rows if there is a duplicate (first, last, email) combination. I've used a loop and performance is not there.
I came up with a query based on `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`

```
INSERT INTO person_info (first_name, last_name, id)
VALUES ( 'v1', 'v2', 'v3'),
( 'v4', 'v5', 'v6'),
( 'v7', 'v8', 'v9')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = VALUES(a), b = VALUES(b), c = VALUES(c);
```

and it is fast and takes care of duplicates. However, now I don't know where to insert extra_info data, because some rows where updated and some are new. I was wondering if there is a way to get a list of id's affected by `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`  with multiple inserts?

Comment: The speed issue is quite possibly the implementation of the 'loop [in code]', not the performance of SQL run on the server as individual statements [within a single connection]. That is, it should be possible to generate the SQL as a series of independent inserts [executed as a batch] using whatever logic as required and collect the output that way. Depending on the number of inserts and client-server latency, simply ensuring the same connection/transaction is re-used in the code loop may be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Are you taking about keeping connection open and looping on cursor?

Comment: ' I don't know where to insert extra_info data, because some rows where updated and some are new.' - not clear what you mean by this.

Comment: the excel sheet contains both person_info and extra_info like this: first_name | last_name | extra1 | extra 2. I cannot insert data in one shot because it is in two different tables that is why I'm using query above to insert all the data fro person_info at one shot but then I'm trying to find out where would corresponding extra1 and extra2 go.